# Custom control generic

Tags: c#

I have a custom control which contains certain fields (textfields) and a button this control is accessed in various other forms.

This user control also contains a Button on click of that button based on what fields are entered i need to do some operation. Now since this user control is used used in many places i do not want others to actually find the control rather do something in a more generalized way.

Like for example:

MyCustom control contains two fields 
Name,Last name and a button search but the grid it binds to is in another Personform

In another form I use myCustomecontrol to do something 
.
Can anyone suggest the way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can expose an event on your control and have the event contain the relevant information in your control.

This class is suitable to contain your event information:

```
public class MyControlSearchEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MyControlSearchEventArgs(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
}
```

Then add this code into your existing custom control class:

```
    public event EventHandler<MyControlSearchEventArgs> SearchClick;

    protected override void OnSearchClick(MyControlSearchEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        EventHandler<MyControlSearchEventArgs> searchClick = SearchClick;

        if(searchClick != null)
            searchClick(this, eventArgs);
    }
```

Now, in the click event handler of your search button, you can raise the event like this:

```
protected void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnSearchClick(new MyControlSearchEventArgs(
        firstNameTextBox.Text, 
        lastNameTextBox.Text
        );
}
```

Consumers of the control will now be able to listen for the `SearchClick` event your control exposes, enabling you to perform any action you wish independently from the control.

**Edit:**

Additionally, if you want to get the values of the two text boxes outside of an event handler, you can expose them as public properties on your control:

```
public string FirstName
{
    get { return firstNameTextBox.Text; }
    set { firstNameTextBox.Text = value; }
}

public string LastName
{
   get { return lastNameTextBox.Text; }
   set { lastNameTextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

You can then get or set these values like it was any ordinary control.

```
SearchControl control = (SearchControl)Page.FindControl("searchControl");
control.FirstName = "Programming";
control.LastName = "Hero";
```

Comment: Hi ,
Thanks for your reply and the beautiful code .
What should i do if i dont have a search button in the form and still want to access all the values in other forms ?
Regards,
Francis

Comment: Updated my answer to include how to expose the values to the rest of your page without the use of an event.